# I am trying to update but it is adding a new row

Tags: php, cakephp

this is my code for updating:
PS: empid is a foreign key but i think that shouldnt be the reason and the code is in CakePHP

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
        {  
            $this->request->data["Leave"]["empid"] = $this->request->data["id"];  
            $this->Leave->empid = $this->request->data["Leave"]["empid"];  
            $this->request->data["Leave"]["leave_start"] = $this->request->data["start_date"];  
            $this->request->data["Leave"]["leave_end"] = $this->request->data["end_date"];  
            $this->request->data["Leave"]["leave_taken"] = $this->request->data["leave_taken"]; 

            if($this->Leave->save($this->request->data['Leave']))
            {
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'manage_leave'));
            }
        }
```

// This code is inserting a new row instead of updating and also not adding any value in the new row

Comment: If you are updating on behalf of foreign key then you need to use updateAll method instead of save. 
If you are updating on behalf of primary key then you need to pass primary key in save data

Answer (score 0):

May be your trying to update the foreign table data using `simple save`.

**Update multiple records for foreign key**

```
Model::updateAll(array $fields, mixed $conditions)
```

Example

```
$this->Ticket->updateAll(
    array('Ticket.status' => "'closed'"),
    array('Ticket.customer_id' => 453)
);
```

**Simple save for the primary key**

Make sure that your HTML has `empid`

```
echo $this->Form->input('Leave.empid', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

Save Model

```
$this->Leave->empid = $this->request->data["Leave"]["empid"]; //2
$this->Leave->save($this->request->data);
```

In between, you can also try to `set` the model data and check the `$this->Leave->validates()` and `$this->Leave->validationError` if they are giving any validation errors.

```
// Create: id isn't set or is null
$this->Recipe->create();
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);

// Update: id is set to a numerical value
$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);
```

You can find more information about all [Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: @AdityaManhas Glad to see that, if it helped you then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

And in case if $empid is primary key of corresponding table of Leave model (e.g leaves), Just replace:

```
$this->Leave->empid = $this->request->data["Leave"]["empid"];
```

By

```
$this->Leave->id = $this->request->data["Leave"]["empid"];
```